# Can not import and use a JavaScript file in my Flask app

Tags: flask

This is a question that have been asked many times but find many answers conflicting and can not get it to work. Some say `Use url_for('static'. filename='my.js')` and other `Create a function to return the path` and others `Define in the initialization of Flask(__name__) where the paths are` and so on. Nothing works and is very confusing.

My app structure looks like this:

```
README
config.py
run.py
setup.py
app/
  blueprint_1/
  blueprint_2/
  templates/
    js/
      myScript.js
    css/
      styles.css
    base.html
    index.html
  __init__.py
```

I run the app in `run.py`, so my source folder is `app/`. I would like to import the JavaScript file in some templates.

How should I do this the "correct way"? Whatever I do now, for example `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('js', filename='myScript.js') }}"></script>` it breaks and say it can not build a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **static** folder directly inside the **app** folder to keep all your static files (like `.js` or `.css` files).
Your tree should look like:

```
README
config.py
run.py
setup.py
app/
  blueprint_1/
  blueprint_2/
  static/
    js/
      myScript.js
    css/
      styles.css
  templates/
    base.html
    index.html
  __init__.py
```

Then you can go ahead and call your script to your templates with:

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/myScript.js') }}"></script>
```

And CSS files with:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
```

Try to use templates folder for only html files. Otherwise it can get messy really quick.